# Finding Differential equation for an equation which is a point

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

What if I have an equation that is like this:

$$
x^2 + y^2 -2cy+c^2=0
$$

$c$ is an arbitrary constant.

I need to find the differential equation for this equation. If I try to find the normal way by differentiating once and substituting $c$ back in the original equation we get something like this:
$$
x^2(1+\frac{1}{(y')^2})=0
$$

or $y'$ simplfies to a complex number.

But if I simplify the original equation we get
$$
x=0
$$
$$
y=c
$$
so what is the correct way to move ahead with this?

Comment: $$y-c=\pm ix\to y'=\pm i\to y'^2+1=0.$$

Answer (score 1):

The equation in $y$ where $x$ is a parameter

$$
(E) \equiv x^2 + y^2 -2cy+c^2=0
$$ has the unique solution $y=c$ if $x=0$ and no real solution otherwise.

Therefore, it is impossible to find a differential equation defining the solution as a solution of a differential equation is by definition defined on an interval of strictly positive length.

Comment: But what if x and y are allowed to be complex numbers. Then can we say the differential equation is possible?

Comment: For complex solutions, you got the solutions in your question. $x^2\left(1+\frac{1}{(y')^2}\right)=0$ implies $1+\frac{1}{(y')^2}$ for $x \neq 0$.

Comment: so if y and x both need to be real then no differential equation is possible else if both x and y are complex then we have can a differential equation

Comment: You should go back to the definition of a differential equation. The solution $y$ can be complex... But the variable (sometimes called the time) $x$ can't. $x$ has to be real. Otherwise, it is something different than a differential equation.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2+y^2-2cy+c^2=0 \tag 1$$
$$x^2+(y-c)^2=0$$
The differential equation is :
$$\boxed{xdx+(y-c)dy=0}\tag 2$$
The particular solution is $(x=0;y=c)$ as expected.

NOTE :

Writing the original equation on the form of a differential equation necessarily introduces an arbitrary constant. This leads to an infinity of solutions. One cannot expect a differential equation which  solution is only Eq.$(1)$.

For solving Eq.$(2)$ we have to consider the case $(y-c)\neq 0$ :
$$y'=\frac{dy}{dx}=-\frac{x}{y-c}\qquad y\neq c$$
Of course the DE is separable, leading to :
$$(y-c)^2=-x^2+C$$
$C$ is an arbitrary constant.

The general solution of Eq.2 is:
$$\begin{cases}
y(x)=c\pm\sqrt{-x^2+C}\\
\text{and}\\
y=c\quad ; \quad x=0
\end{cases}$$
Don't expect to find a DE which general solution is EQ.$(1)$ only.